# Binary tree height is this correct?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

[image]

High guys what is the height of the tree above? its 3 right?

the test cases designed by my teacher expects it to be 2.

this is the code i use to obtain the height;

```
public int height(TreeNode t){

if (t == null)
return 0;
int heightLeft = height(t.leftChild);
int heightRight = height(t.rightChild)

if( heightLeft > heightRight )
return heightLeft +1;
else
return heightRight +1;
}
```

Why would you close this thread??

Comment: you're getting negative votes cause 10 seconds of google searching will get you your answer

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

> The depth (or height) of a tree is the length of the path from the root to the deepest node in the tree. A (rooted) tree with only one node (the root) has a depth of zero.